# Android - how to get google plus access token?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-play, access-token

Hello i am getting google plus access token without using  OAuth 2.0 client ID with scopes. But with this access token does not fetch email address. How to fetch user email address?

Is there any difference between accesstoken with and without  OAuth 2.0 client ID?

I have used following code,

```
String accessToken="";
                    try {
                        accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                mPlusClient.getAccountName(), "oauth2:"
                                        + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " "
                                        + Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE);

                        System.out.println("Access token==" + accessToken);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Show some code that you have tried.

Comment: What exception you are getting ?

Comment: No exception but, with this access code i am getting user's profile info without email id, on server side

Comment: That means you are getting the Access Token ?

Comment: Yes but does not getting email id if i request with this access token

Comment: if i put access here, token https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token= .............

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String accessToken = "";
try {
  URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo");
  // get Access Token with Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE
  String sAccessToken;
  sAccessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
    LoginCheckActivity.this,
    mPlusClient.getAccountName() + "",
    "oauth2:"
      + Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE + " "
      + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" + " "
      + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read");
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();                  
  Intent recover = e.getIntent();
  startActivityForResult(recover, 125);
  return "";
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @Deprecated
    public static String getToken(Context var0, String var1, String var2)

Answer (score 14):

There are 2 simple ways to get user Email from Google plus,

1.Through `Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName` like below,

`String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);`

2.Through `plus.profile.emails.read scope and REST end point` like below,

**Get the GooglePlus AccessToken**

You need to pass `" https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"` this scope to get the `AccessToken` from GooglePlus like below,

```
accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                mPlusClient.getAccountName(), "oauth2:"
                                        + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " "
                                        + Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE+" https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read");
```

**Make a REST call to the endpoint and do simple JSON parsing**

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX

You must declare the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to use these methods.

**Full Example from Google Developer site,**

Do something like below to retrieve the authenticated user's Email from Google plus,

```
class UserInfo {
  String id;
  String email;
  String verified_email;
}

final String account = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

  @Override
  protected UserInfo doInBackground(Void... params) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
      URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me");
      String sAccessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(EmailTest.this, account,
        "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read");

      urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + sAccessToken);

      String content = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(),
          Charsets.UTF_8));

      if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(content)) {
        JSONArray emailArray =  new JSONObject(content).getJSONArray("emails");

        for (int i = 0; i < emailArray.length; i++) {
          JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)emailArray.get(i);

          // Find and return the primary email associated with the account
          if (obj.getString("type") == "account") {
            return obj.getString("value");
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userAuthEx) {
      // Start the user recoverable action using the intent returned by
      // getIntent()
      startActivityForResult(userAuthEx.getIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
      return;
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // Handle error
      // e.printStackTrace(); // Uncomment if needed during debugging.
    } finally {
      if (urlConnection != null) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String info) {
      // Store or use the user's email address
  }

};

task.execute();
```

Fore more info read this

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people

Comment: I have edited my answer with some more info. Hope it will help you.