# How do I get access token using Google plus

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I have followed [this](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-google-oauth2.html) tutorial in order to get the `access token` and it works as shown in the link. Now how do I get the email and profile pic from this? I have implemented [found this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android) which shows me how to quick start with google+ signin.

But in this how do I get the access token?

I have found these links which shows me the basic part but can anyone say me where do I need to implement them ?

- [Get Google Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759529/android-how-to-get-google-plus-access-token)
- [With Asynctask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547019/calling-this-from-your-main-thread-can-lead-to-deadlock-and-or-anrs-while-getti/17547891#17547891)

So how do I use this using AsyncTask

Finally I would like to get the access token, email and profile pic and how from anyone of the tutorial?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ways. This is the easiest to understand. First, build a class extending `AsyncTask<>`. You want a `String[]` to be the return type. Note: `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`  so if you want to return a string, you need to extend `AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>`

```
 public class YourAsyncTaskName extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String token = null;

            try {
                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        mGoogleApiClient.getAccountName(),
                        "oauth2:" + SCOPES);
            } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                // Network or server error, try later
                Log.e(TAG, transientEx.toString());

            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                // Recover (with e.getIntent())
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());  

            } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                // The call is not ever expected to succeed
                // assuming you have already verified that 
                // Google Play services is installed.
                Log.e(TAG, authEx.toString());
            }

            return token;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
            /* here you have your token */
            Log.i(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + token);
        }

 }
```

Then to start this task, just create an instance and call `.execute();`

```
YourAsyncTaskName asyncTask = new AsyncTaskName();
asyncTask.execute();
```