# Can we embedd appkey at the time google plus login in android code

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus

what we want is , to implement dynamic ness in android code and which is performed in facebook and twitter but by adding app key in facebook and seckey and consumer key in twitter but in g+ login there is no option to add appkey dynamically please suggest a way to embedd appkey in code .

But in ios there is GPSignin class which they can use to embedd appkey at runtime ... How google can do that to us , google is ours.

Comment: Why do you need it ?

Comment: After searching i think : google outh2.0 is my answer ... i have to work on that

Comment: you think or you know what you want ? You don't have to set the Key or something on the runtime to use Oauth2. You can use GoogleApiClient to get the user credentials.

Comment: Its our need ... we are making a dynamic app in which we can add any google app login ... so we have to work on outh because i think ouyh requires apikey ... but google+ sign in only works on package we difined at app creation time we can add appkey dynamically in google+ sign in

Comment: is that something you may want, [SOF Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759529/android-how-to-get-google-plus-access-token)

Comment: Yes that question is how want to perform

Comment: No man ... tomorrow i have to try that ... and will let you know about that ... actually facebook had given that facility to add apikey at runtime