# Spring OAuth2.0: Where does spring store the access token?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am using `Spring Oauth2.0` using Google as authorization provider. I have the following configuration in my `application.yml` file

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      clientSecret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      accessTokenUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: query
      scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

And this is my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);    
    }

    @Bean public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

}
```

After this I need to access google api to get some user info but that requires an access token. Where does Spring store this token? How can I retrieve it? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: you should have a class to configure OAuth2 then you can define a tokenStore that can be on memory or database.

Comment: Take a look at `TokenStore` http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/TokenStore.html

Comment: Useful link [how to get access token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759529/android-how-to-get-google-plus-access-token)

Comment: @AbelRoussi Thanks for the comment. But I am not able to make it work. It says GoogleAuthUtil not resolved even though I imported the appropriate lib. Looks like this works only for Android. You sure this will work with spring?

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval thanks for the comment, can u provide link to some tutorial or example. I didn't find any related to tokenStore. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) documentation about Spring and social login, then when you get more experience could try to put an auth micro service that store your tokens on redis. I use a gateway pattern with Outlook and have to specify a url in the client configuration where the oauth server will retrieve the token and some data specified in the request.

I hope it helps.